# c# How to open a Word file and set the path is relative to the project folder

Tags: c#, opencv, path

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"export.doc");
ap.Visible = true;
```

I try this, but i need set the path is relative to the project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.StartupPath`:

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Document document = ap.Documents.Open(Application.StartupPath + @"\export.doc");
ap.Visible = true;
```